# How to format a number such a way that there is always one fractional digit?

Tags: iphone, nsnumberformatter

For example, I have float values like:

0.2
1.5
2.0
3.0
10.0
52.5
60.0

Under any circumstances, I really want one fractional digit. Even if the number is exactly 1, i want it to be displayed as 1.0

I tried to set up an NSNumberFormatter like this, but it doesn't work:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
[formatter setAllowsFloats:YES];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];

[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[formatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:2];

[formatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

It shows 0.2, 5.0, 5.5, 9.0,

but when it reaches 10, it would show 10, 10.3, 11, 11.9, 15, ... and so on.
Is this something NSNumberFormatter can't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

NSString * f= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f",(float)10];

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but if you are in a place where the comma us used for the . it should work just fine. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/lconv/

Comment: @openfrog use 'localizedStringWithFormat' to localize the decimal separator

Answer (score 2):

> **setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:**
>   Controls whether the receiver always shows the decimal separator, even for integer numbers.

Try setting this to YES

Comment: It will force a decimal separator, but it doesn't make sure there's always exactly one fractional digit after the separator... it produces things like 10. or 15. but not 10.0 or 15.5 ...

Answer (score 0):

I could not use [madmi3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3807753/3927536) solution's because I need to set the locale of the NSNumberFormatter dynamically.

So ended up using the following solution:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = YES; // This will produce results like 10. for intergers
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt"]; // I get this locale dinamically

NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10]];

//Check this formattedNumber is ending with the separator
//If so, then append one more 0.
if ([formattedNumber hasSuffix:[formatter.locale objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]])
{
    formattedNumber = [formattedNumber stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
}

NSLog(@"%@", formattedNumber);
```